# Filtering WooCommerce REST API Endpoints for Reports

Tags: wordpress, rest, woocommerce

I am trying to add a filter to the following class in WooCommerce; WC_REST_Report_Orders_Totals_Controller using the following code to add an item into the array.

```
function filter_report($response, $report, $request) {
    $response['test'] = 'test123';
    
    return $response;
}
add_filter('filter_report', array('WC_REST_Report_Orders_Totals_Controller', 'woocommerce_rest_prepare_report_orders_count'), 10, 3);
```

However, when viewing the REST API endpoint where this code is triggered, nothing is modified. I have also tried creating an instance of the class and passing it into the array on the add filter instead but this does not seem to work either.

Thank you.